# Flatten numpy array with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Here is an example to reproduce my problem:

```
a = np.array([[1,2], [3,4], [6,7]])
b = np.array([[1,2], [3,4], [6,7,8]])
c = np.array([[1,2], [3,4], [6]])
print(a.flatten())
print(b.flatten())
print(c.flatten())
```

The problem exist when one of the arrays has an item less or more.

```
Output:
[1 2 3 4 6 7]
[list([1, 2]) list([3, 4]) list([6, 7, 8])] # Won't work
[list([1, 2]) list([3, 4]) list([6])]       # Also won't work

How I want it:
[1 2 3 4 6 7]
[1 2 3 4 6 7 8]
[1 2 3 4 6]
```

Does anyone know how to flatten the list properly for example b and c?

Comment: `flatten` works on 2d arrays; it changes the shape.  Your `b` (and 'c') is not 2d; it's 1d, already flat.  You might need to step back and (re)read `numpy` documentation about `shape` (and `flatten` and `dtype`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `concatenate`

```
np.concatenate(b)
Out[204]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8])
np.concatenate(c)
Out[205]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 6])
```

Answer (score 1):

You need:

```
from itertools import chain

a = np.array([[1,2], [3,4], [6,7]])

b = np.array([[1,2], [3,4], [6,7,8]])

c = np.array([[1,2], [3,4], [6]])

print(a.flatten())
print(list(chain(*b)))
print(list(chain(*c)))
```

Output:

```
[1 2 3 4 6 7]
[1 2 3 4 6 7 8]
[1 2 3 4 6]
```