# how can I change a two dimensional array to one dimensional

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to change a two dimensional array to one dimensional, my code is like this:

```
x = np.array([[1, 2, 4], [3, 4], [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]])
x = x.flatten()
```

however, I found that flatten function works well on

```
x = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
```

but it does not work  on

```
x = np.array([[1, 2, 4], [3, 4], [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]])
```

could anyone help me to change

```
np.array([[1, 2, 4], [3, 4], [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]])
```

to

```
np.array([[1, 2, 4, 3, 4, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
```

thank you

Comment: Just earlier today, a question about flattening - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52970017/flatten-numpy-array-with-python.  The key point is that your `x` is not two dimensional.  It is 1d!  Check it's `shape` if you don't believe me.  It's a 1d object dtype array of lists.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flatten numpy array with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52970017/flatten-numpy-array-with-python)

Comment: @PaulRooney, your link is all about `reshape`, which `flatten` attempts to do.  That's not applicable here.

Answer (score 7):

You can try using `concatenate` ([numpy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html)):

```
flatten_x = np.concatenate(x)
```

Comment: I've got `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'concatenate'`

Comment: Can you try changing `x` to numpy array by using `np.array(x)` before calling concantenate?

Answer (score 1):

```
t = [[4, 9, 2], [3, 5, 7], [8, 1, 5]]
arr_t=[]
for a in t:
    arr_t+=a
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the following simple code.

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[1, 2, 4], [3, 4], [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]])
y = sum(x.tolist(),[])
print(np.array(y))
```